# Is it possible to attach local images to selfbot messages with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm teaching myself to send automated messages through discord using Node.js, discord.js, and https://github.com/rigwild/discord-self-bot-console. This isn't for use through an official discord bot, it's through a user account. (I'm aware this is a ban risk, it's just for a personal project)

The issue I ran into was trying to upload local images. While I can get discord to display text and to attach image urls, every time I try to upload a local file, the text is sent but the file is never attached. I also don't want to do it as an embed, just as an attachment.

(I have discord.js 14.8.0 and node-fetch ^2.6.6)

Here's my actual code:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const fs = require('fs');

// Discord self-bot API here, found at https://gist.github.com/rigwild/6063278cbc9267e7691c084c67176114

(async () => {

// Function to send a message with a local file
    async function sendMessageWithFile(channelOrThreadId, message, filePath) {
        const fileData = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath); // Read file data
        console.log(fileData)
        const sentMessage = await api.sendMessage(channelOrThreadId, '', false, body = {
            content: message,
            files: [
                {
                    attachment: fileData,
                    name: 'chosen.png' // Replace with the name of the file you want to send
                }
            ]
        });
        return sentMessage;
    }

// Usage example
    const channelId = ''; // Replace with the ID of the channel you want to send the message to
    const filePath = ''; // Replace with the path to the file you want to send
    sendMessageWithFile(channelId, 'Here is a local file:', filePath)
        .then(sentMessage => {
            console.log('Message sent:', sentMessage);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error sending message:', error);
        });
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey it's allways posible if you use a image link that would make it a lot easier for you. Or you can use the build in discord.js MessageAttachment('Image.png')